# Getting Selected Row Value

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to get the selected row value from a DataGrid in WPF, and it's proving to be very frustrating. It's simple in WinForms, though.

How can I get the selected *or* a specified single row value from a datagrid control in wpf?

I have used several snippets i've found online, and all of them give me the contents of the whole row, including the column names!

I have tried:

```
string value = dataGrid1.SelectedItems[0].ToString();

string value = dataGrid1.SelectedCells[dataGrid1.SelectedItems[0]].ToString();
```

I've looked on MSDN under the wpf controls section but can't see how I can get a row value anywhere.

All I keep getting back is:
`{ OrderId = d#dfuzJRo , UserId = 56, OrderTotal = , Freight = , DeliveryStatus = , OrderStatus = Pending, TransactionId = , OrderDate = 16/08/2011 9:12:00 PM }` - which isn't what I'm after.

I would like to get the OrderId when I double-click on a Row.

My XAML is setup like:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="dataGrid1" DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#4D0090FF" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#A30091FF" AlternatingRowBackground="#200098FF" BorderThickness="0" ClipToBounds="False" MouseDoubleClick="dataGrid1_MouseDoubleClick" Margin="0,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></DataGrid>
```

And I am getting DB info successfully (based off of MSDN tutorial) like:

```
    private void ViewOrders()
    {
        ObjectQuery<Order> orders = dEntities.Orders;

        var query = from order in orders
                    orderby order.OrderStatus
                    select new
                    {
                        order.OrderId,
                        order.UserId,
                        order.OrderTotal,
                        order.Freight,
                        order.DeliveryStatus,
                        order.OrderStatus,
                        order.TransactionId,
                        order.OrderDate
                    };
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `SelectedItem`?  If you want a detailed answer, provide some details. What are you binding to and how?

Comment: Thanks @Henk, I have updated my question with my code and what I've tried etc.

Comment: Have you tried something like `Order order = dataGrid.SelectedItem as Order`, and then `var orderId = order.OrderId`?

Comment: @jase: the selected item is a whole row.

Comment: @Henk, hehe, boy do i feel silly now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the simple `SelectedItem` or `SelectedItems[0]` will give you the row. But your row is an anonymous type, that makes getting the `OrderID` a little difficult.

The simple approach is to simply select the `order` item and display that. Set up column definitions in the grid to select which properties to show.

The alternative is to define a `class DisplayOrder`, and then change the Linq query:

```
   select new DisplayOrder
   {
       order.OrderId,
       ...
   };
```

In both cases, you can simply access `SelectedItem.OrderID` from the grid.

```
  var row = (DisplayOrder) datagrid1.SelectedItem;  // or (Order)
  int Id = row.OrderID;
```

Comment: Ow that's a nice solution. Thank you so much @Henk. :)