# INSERT statement tries to insert data to column, which is not given in the code

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, insert

I try to insert data to column ansatID in the table shown on the picture. User has to mark a row in DataGridView, insert his ID in the textBox1 on the left, then press button ''Tilføj ansat til vagten'' and his ID should be inserted into column ansatID for marked row in DataGridView. But I get error message: ''Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Dato', table 'Vagtplan.dbo.Vagter'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.'' My wondering is why does the statement try to insert data to 'Dato' column?? I have tried following code:

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            String ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS01;Initial Catalog=Vagtplan;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            myconnection.Open();

            SqlCommand AddNumberCommand = myconnection.CreateCommand();
            AddNumberCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.Vagter ([ansatID]) VALUES (@ansatID)";

            AddNumberCommand.Parameters.Add("@ansatID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox1.Text;

            AddNumberCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            myconnection.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Du har valgt vagten.");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Columd ansatID is foreign key in the table and the column ansatID is nullable. 
The expected result is that ansatID should be inserted into column ansatID for marked row in DataGridView. The table is show on the attached picture.

[image: Picture]

Comment: Based on the error message, Dato is a non-nullable type. Since you are not providing a value for it, sql will insert null. You should make the type nullable in SSMS.

Comment: Your insert needs to provide a value for the `Dato` column, because `Dato` does not allow nulls and has no default value. When you insert a row, something has to go in `Dato`. It's got nothing. You need to provide something.

Comment: When you `INSERT` a row a value for every column is evaluated. If no value is passed then the `DEFAULT` value is used, is there isn't one then the column will be populated with `NULL`. You haven't defined `Dato` in your `INSERT` and it appears it doesn't have a `DEFAULT` value, so `NULL` is used, however, as the column is set to `NOT NULL` the value is not allowed and the `INSERT` fails.

Comment: On a different note, it's so nice to see a well formed question and someone using  a parametrised statement with `Parameters.Add`; keep up the good work :)

Answer (score 0):

> his ID should be inserted into column ansatID for marked row in
>   DataGridView

This is the wrong way. You try to UPDATE a column. What are your primary key?

```
UPDATE dbo.Vagter set [ansatID] = @ansatID WHERE MyPK = @myPk;
```

Comment: Primary Keys are defined in column 'Dato'

Comment: Then you can 
`UPDATE dbo.Vagter set [ansatID] = @ansatID WHERE Dato = @dato;`
You apply the dato parameter in the same way as first parameter. Here you find, how you can fetch a value from a seleted row:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7138569/getting-selected-row-value)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using `INSERT`. An `INSERT` statement inserts a full *row* of data. In your case, since you're only specifying a value for one column, SQL Server will try to insert `NULL` into all of the columns you haven't named, and that's what's throwing the error you're seeing. Your `INSERT` statement is well formatted (nicely done!), but it's not really the statement you want.

You're looking for an `UPDATE` statement. It will look something like this:

```
...
AddNumberCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE dbo.Vagter SET [ansatID] = @ansatID WHERE <Primary Key Field(s) Here> = <Appropriate Value(s)>";
...
```

Comment: Okey, now I understand :) But how to define (in the Sql statement) value of the primary key in the marked row ?

Comment: I was sort of hoping you already had that stored someplace so you'd know what to show in your datagrid. :) You may need to do a two-step, querying the row they highlighted to update so you know where to send the entered data.

Comment: Okey, and how will this UPDATE statement look like, if I have to do it in two steps?

Comment: I'm afraid my C# is only good enough to read code, not to write it. You could post another question asking how to get the primary key value(s) for a row selected in a data grid, though, and I'm sure someone here can help.